# BIM 360 Collaboration Files not showing on viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

i forked the demo viewer project, it works great, i can see all files from BIM 360 in the forge tree , personal hub and others. But i have a problem with files that were initiated with Collaboration for revit. im not sure why but those are not visible for me in the tree.

i added the app id in the BIM 360 account so im not sure whats the issue

im working with the basic project samples https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/tutorials/viewhubmodels

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're using the .NET Core version of that tutorial, right?

There is a small problem there, [at this line](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/learn.forge.viewhubmodels/blob/netcore/Controllers/DataManagementController.cs#L178), where the `visibleTypes` attribute returned by the API does not include `C4R` models, therefore the sample does not show them. Sorry about that, it will be fixed.

Comment: Hi Augusto, thanks a lo for the answer, if its not too much truouble could you give me an approximate date, or alternative method, we have develop a solution for a client but is pretty much useless if they cant access the Collaboration models.

Comment: one quick fix would be to add that type to the list anyway.